# How can I display a drop-down select of Post Names

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I would like to add a custom write panel to a custom post type. I'm looking at the the code here:

http://wefunction.com/2009/10/revisited-creating-custom-write-panels-in-wordpress/

I can get the custom write panel to appear on a standard post edit page but not for my registered custom post type.

```
add_meta_box( 'int_parent_meta', ucfirst( $key ) . 'Options',
    'display_meta_box', 'name-of-custom-post-type', 'normal', 'high' );
```

If I replace 'name-of-custom-post-type' with 'post' in the above line, the panel appears on the post edit screen.

Anyone know what I'm missing here? Wordpress version is 3.0.1

Comment: Maybe you are not correctly writing the name of your custom post type? What is its actual name? Can you show your register_post_type code?

Comment: Can you show us the full code your using (perhaps in a pastebin)?  My first instinct is that your custom post type isn't being registered with support for custom meta boxes ...

Comment: thanks - I think I had my arguments incorrect for add_meta_box. Its working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the fourth argument should be the name of the custom post type, as defined when you created the post type. see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

For a clearer explanation of how to successfully create metaboxes, see [this tutorial](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/04/how-to-create-meta-box-wordpress-post.html)

the second argument should be the callback function, you can create the drop down HTML in a function, and place the function name in this argument and you'll have your pull down menu.

Comment: thanks! That tutorial looks better than the others I found.